# When traverse a HashMap, I get NullPointerException

Tags: java, dictionary

This is my code:

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map;
....// I didn't write those code that initial the map.
System.out.println(map.entrySet().size()); // run util here is ok, I get the size of the map.
for(Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {// here throw the exception
    Sytem.out.println("abc");// didn't executed, throw exception before
}
```

And I get the exception:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at key.test.EnwikiOutlink.main(EnwikiOutlink.java:68)**

The map object has more than 10,000 map objects, I run it in server machine and couldn't debug. 
But when I decrease the size of this map(under 10,000), program runs ok.
What's the reason of the problem, and the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Is line 68 the one shown calling `map.entrySet`?

Comment: I don't think that the line highlighted can be line 68. Possibly it is line 68 now, but maybe it wasn't before you added the println?

Comment: Does the program actually work for 9999 objects and break for 10,000? Also, are you modifying map inside that `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

Where is `map` initialized? If you don't actually assign anything to it, of course it will be `null`.

(It's not clear if it's a class member or a local variable.)

Comment: I didn't write it, and I'm sure the map is not null, because when I print the size of map.entrySet().size(), I got it. I update the question, sorry for not clear befor.

Comment: In which case the NPE must be coming from another line, most likely within the loop. As @Jon Skeet suggests, what exactly is line 68?

Answer (score 1):

If the map *does* contain elements, then `map.entrySet()` won't throw `NullPointerException` (because the map is not null), so the exception must be coming from accessing one of the elements (or its subobjects) in the loop.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter one bit whether the map contains any elements.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - you are correct, entrySet() would work on an empty map, (but not on a null reference); my point was: if it actually contained elments, it cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this: and it worked fine. Your map must be assigned to null somewhere.

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map;
map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

for(Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

}
```

Comment: @TomQuarendon I was so baffled that there was a Question asking this that I HAD TO try it. It was too obvious (and if I encounter stuff that's too obvious I tend to try it, just to be sure). ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `map` is a local variable (and not an instance field), it is *theoretically impossible* to get an NPE on `map.entrySet()` after `map.entrySet().size()` already succeeded, even if the map itself was accessible to another thread and that thread changed it in every way imaginable. If the first entry in your stacktrace is a line of your code, as opposed to some code that was called from yours, then the only way for that to happen is for the `map` variable itself to be `null`. Therefore I think you need to revisit your diagnostic clues.