# A HashMap's traverse, I get NullPointerException

Tags: java, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When traverse a HashMap, I get NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140022/when-traverse-a-hashmap-i-get-nullpointerexception)

This is my code:

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map;

....//I didn't write those code.

System.out.println(map.entrySet().size()); // run util here is ok, I get the size of the map.
for(Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {// here throw the exception

}
```

And I get the exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at key.test.EnwikiOutlink.main(EnwikiOutlink.java:68)

The map object has more than 10,000 map objects, I run it in server machine and couldn't debug. But when I decrease the size of this map(under 10,000), program runs ok. What's the reason of the problem, and the solution? Thanks!

Comment: So there's nothing in between the `System.out` and the for loop? And you definitely get the NPE in that for line?

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap allows null in values**. So in your HashMap if the **HashSet is null**, you will get NullPointerException. **Make sure that HashSet is not null**.

Comment: You mean entry(HashSet<String, HashSet<String>) is null or HashSet<String> is null?

Comment: `HashSet<String>` could be null.